# iOS swift-charts : Missing intermediate values

Tags: ios, ios-charts

I would like to create charts using Swift charts lib. I quickly tried to create an example line chart, but the intermediate values are missing. It is drawing only the two first values of the array (5 and 6).

Code :

```
    var ccv:CombinedChartView = CombinedChartView()
    //CombinedChartData

    ccv.delegate = self;

    //ccv.chartDescription.enabled = false;

    ccv.drawGridBackgroundEnabled = false;
    ccv.drawBarShadowEnabled = false;
    ccv.highlightFullBarEnabled = false;

    // Line

    var lds:LineChartDataSet = LineChartDataSet(yVals: Array(arrayLiteral:
        ChartDataEntry(value: 5, xIndex: 0),
        ChartDataEntry(value: 6, xIndex: 1),
        ChartDataEntry(value: 7, xIndex: 2),
        ChartDataEntry(value: 3, xIndex: 3)
        ), label: "Sample")
    lds.colors = [UIColor.redColor()]
    lds.mode = LineChartDataSet.Mode.CubicBezier
    lds.drawValuesEnabled = true

    var ld:LineChartData = LineChartData(xVals: Array(arrayLiteral: 0, 1, 2, 3, 4), dataSets: Array(arrayLiteral:lds))
    var ccd:CombinedChartData = CombinedChartData()
    ccd.lineData = ld

    ccv.data = ccd
    ccv.setScaleEnabled(true)


    ccv.frame = (self.chartContainer?.frame)!
    ccv.frame.origin.x = 0
    ccv.frame.origin.y = 0
    self.chartContainer?.addSubview(ccv)
```

Any help is welcome :)

Comment: Ok I found a way to manage this working :

Answer (score 0):

Ok found a way to manage this :

```
    let ccv:CombinedChartView = CombinedChartView()
    //CombinedChartData

    ccv.delegate = self;

    //ccv.chartDescription.enabled = false;

    ccv.drawGridBackgroundEnabled = false;
    ccv.drawBarShadowEnabled = false;
    ccv.highlightFullBarEnabled = false;

    // Line

    let lds:LineChartDataSet = LineChartDataSet(yVals: Array(arrayLiteral:
        ChartDataEntry(value: 5, xIndex: 0),
        ChartDataEntry(value: 6, xIndex: 1),
        ChartDataEntry(value: 7, xIndex: 2),
        ChartDataEntry(value: 3, xIndex: 3)
        ), label: "Toto")
    lds.colors = [UIColor.redColor()]
    lds.mode = LineChartDataSet.Mode.CubicBezier
    lds.drawValuesEnabled = true

    let ld:LineChartData = LineChartData(xVals: Array(arrayLiteral: 0, 1, 2, 3), dataSets: Array(arrayLiteral:lds))
    let ccd:CombinedChartData = CombinedChartData(xVals: Array(arrayLiteral: 0, 1, 2, 3))
    ccd.lineData = ld

    ccv.data = ccd
    ccv.setScaleEnabled(true)


    ccv.frame = (self.chartContainer?.frame)!
    ccv.frame.origin.x = 0
    ccv.frame.origin.y = 0
    self.chartContainer?.addSubview(ccv)
```